# Badges are too cheap

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-progress

Why did you made badges so cheap? They are given way too soon. I have recently received the "Organizer" badge only after one approved edit.

One should earn a badge after a substantial good-quality input.

Comment: Try going for the golden badges, such as [Socratic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic) and [Legendary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/52/legendary) to see the difference between bronze badges awarded for learning about a feature of the site and golden badges awarding outstanding contributions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is by design. Bronze badges are [intended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges) to be cheap; they teach you about certain features and rules of the site.

> 1. **Bronze badges**. Bronze badges are awarded for basic use of the site; they encourage people to use all the typical, routine functions of the site: posting questions, answering questions, voting up or down, tagging posts, editing, filling out your user profile, and so forth. Bronze badges are relatively easy to get.

Properly tagging a question is one of those rules, and therefore you receive a badge for something as simple as changing the tags on somebody else's question. Note that unlike reputation, bronze badges do not give additional privileges, they just look nice.